# Extend Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

As I use Notepad++ daily at work, I want to extend it to be more productive.

What i want to do is select multiple lines containing words, right click and click a menu item like "Comma separate" then get all words on a single line comma separated.

I know that Notepad++ has support for macros and plugins. What would be the best way to do this?

I've got limited C++ skills.

**Update:**

To clarify, it's never more than 5 or 6 lines of words i need to re-format. The problem is that I do this like 50 times a day, so a way to speed up this would be great. Is there any other application that can do this for me?

**Update2**

Thanks for your answers. I'm going to try creating a Notepad++ plugin.

**Update3**

Does anyone know of a .NET-wrapper to create a Notepad++ plugin? Maybe this should be a new question.

Comment: sound like something I would do with a search-replace, optionally with a regular expression like replace "(\b.+?\b)\s*" with "$1;"

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing how to extend Notepad++ with plugins (or some other extensible text editor)

Comment: What's your point saying that the offered solutions don't save you time because you only have 5 or 6 lines? What do you expect from the macro or plugin you talk about and what steps are you willing to do?

Comment: Because if it's just 5 or 6 lines, it would be faster for me just to manually place all words comma separated on a single line.

What i want to do is select all lines, right click and then choose someting like "comma separate". A keyword shortcut would do it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often use Notepad++'s macro function for things like this.

Eg. Say you have this:

```
apple
pear
banana
grape
orange
```

To comma separate lines, you could go to the first line, press ctrl+r (start recording), then end, delete, comma, then ctrl+r again to stop recording.

Then press control+p (play recording) repeatedly until you have what you want. If I'm processing a large file, I just hold it down, then ctrl+z my way back if I go too far.

You can't save your macro for later, but something that simple is easy to do again.

**Edit:** Actually, it turns out you *can* save your macro for later, and even assign a hotkey to it. Just record the macro, then go `Macro -> Save current recorded macro`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution won't save me time as it's often just 5 or 6 rows i need to replace.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this easily now with the Python Scripting plugin for Notepad++.

Just add a script with something like

```
text = editor.getSelText()
text = text.replace(' ', ',')
editor.replaceSel(text)
```

Assign the script a shortcut or toolbar button and you're away.  I'm not totally clear on what you want to replace, but obviously changing the logic of the script should be pretty easy.

Comment: I was about to propose the same solution. Just discovered this plugin and it can do a lot of powerful stuff.

Answer (score 3):

As he's asking for a .NET approach in his last edit, here we go:

[Notepad++ .NET plugin template for Visual Studio and SharpDevelop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.6.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Notepad++ you have to use this string to match single word in a line, possibly with trailing spaces:

`^\<(.*)\> *$`

and then you replace the words with `\1,`

I tried to do this myself, everything worked, except after this you have to switch from regex search mode to extended and delete all `\r\n` or `\n` depending on your line endings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on PhiLho's answer:

1. Close Notepad++
2. Edit %AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml in any text editor other than N++
3. Find <Macros> tag and paste inside the code below:

   ```
   <Macro name="Lines to comma separated text" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">
       <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
       <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\r\n" />
       <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
       <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="," />
       <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
       <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
   </Macro>
   ```
4. Save, close and open Notepad++ - you'll see a new macro in "Macro" menu with key shortcut set to Alt+Shift+R (easy to configure inside shortcuts.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Let see.
I have 5 lines of word. I select them. Ctrl+H. Check Extended and In selection. Search '\r\n', replace with ',', hit Replace All.
I got mostly the result you want (with an extra comma at the end).

Is that what you want? Perhaps you can make a macro out of it, I don't know much about this capability (I mostly use SciTE actually).

Comment: Yes, this is the behaviour i'm after. Unfortnuately, this won't save me that much time, as it's often just 5 or 6 lines of words.

Comment: Tried with latest Notepad++, it still doesn't make macros out of Find/Search dialogs (probably use Scintilla's macro capability).
Unless I miss something, I fear you have to write a C++ plugin, which is a bit of overkill for your need. Too bad NPP doesn't support scripting like SciTE does. It would be quite trivial to do in Lua...